# Spring Boot form data binding a list with FreeMarker

Tags: java, forms, spring-boot, data-binding, freemarker

I am trying to bind my form to a data transfer object. The form is a FreeMarker template. They are as follows:

The Data object:

```java
@Data
public class TransferObject {
    private List<Subclass> subclassInstances;

    public TransferObject(Data data) {
        // this takes the data and populates the object, also works
        // we end up with a list of subclasses.
    }

    @Data //lombok -> generates getters and setters
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class Subclass {
        private String id;
        private String code;
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```java
@GetMapping({"/endpoint", "/endpoint"})
public String endpoint(Model model, @RequestParam(value="code", required=false, defaultValue="") String code) {

    // this retrieves the data, but that works so it's irrelevant here
    Data data = this.dataService.findByCode(code).orElse(null);

    if(data != null) {
        TransferObject transferObject = new TransferObject(data);
        model.addAttribute("data", transferObject);

    } else {
        log.warn("no data found");
    }

    return "endpoint";
}
```

The Freemarker template:

```html
<form:form action="/endpoint" method="post" modelAttribute="data">
    <#if data??>
        <#list data.subclasses as subclass>
            ${subclass} <!-- this shows an object with 2 fields that are filled -->

            <@spring.bind "data.subclasses[${subclass?index}].id"/>
            <input type="text" value="${subclass.id}"/> <!-- This line fails -->

            <@spring.bind "data.subclasses[${subclass?index}].code"/>
            <input type="text" value="${subclass.code}"/>

        </#list>
    </#if>
</form:form>
```

There is an error in the template that states:
[The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> sublcass.id] I don't get that because I print the subclass just above that and it is there..

I also tried changing

```html
<input type="text" value="${subclass.id}"/>
```

to

```html
<input type="text" value="${data.subclasses[subclass?index].id}"/>
```

But then it tells me that 'data' is null or missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message regarding `subclass.id` means that `subclass` is there, but it has no `id` subvariable.

Comment: That is not the case here. when I print ```data.subclasses[${subclass?index}]``` on the line above it gives me: ```Data.Sublclass(id=1,code=1111)``` so it's just the ```.id``` part that doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after all:

The problem was in the TranferObject. The Sublclass class has *`private`* access. so any getters or setters aren't found. That's why the FreeMarker template could not find the `.id` property.

When I tried to access the getter in normal Java code I got a compilation error:
`Error:(65, 77) java: getId() in Data.Subclass is defined in an inaccessible class or interface`
Which in my opinion is better than exclaiming it's null or missing.